# My Website’s Main URL redirects me to an Archive Page

Tags: urls, archives, homepage, domain, home-url

desperately need your help as I’m completely new to this concept called “WordPress”. When I visit [www.mydomainname.com](http://www.mydomainname.com), it automatically pulls a page that shows “Archive” right under my Logo and the Menu on the right hand side. To visit my actual home page, I have to click on “Home” from the menu and only then, my actual home page shows up, but with a /home as a suffix to my domain name. Example: [www.mydomainname.com/home](http://www.mydomainname.com/home)
This happened when I was building and editing my homepage with Elementor (while getting trained on using Elementor). I would like that when someone types my my domainname.com, that they land on my actual home page without them having to click on the “Home” menu.
If someone could please help me with detailed steps as this is the fort time Im using WordPress or even building my website.

Thanks so very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**1**. Go to `Appearance` → `Customize`.

**2**. Select `Homepage Settings`.

**3**. Select `A static page`.

**4**. From the drop-down menu under `Homepage`, choose selected page as the front page for your site.

**5**. Click `Save Changes`.